# Doubt about an integral

Tags: real-analysis

If
$$ \oint_{C_{1}}\vec{F} . d \vec{r}= \int \int (Q_{x}-P_{y})dxdy \\=\int \int dxdy=\pi$$

However this doesn't lead me to anything.  All I get is that the area for $r = 1$ is $\frac{\pi}{ 3}$ and with that I can't get the circulation for any radius less than one so I'm not knowing how to do this exercise.  I appreciate all help!

Comment: To apply Green's Theorem you need your function $F$ to have continuous derivatives on the whole disc bounded by $C_r$. Since $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0))$ and all the circles $C_r$ are centered at the origin, this condition is not satisfied.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Taking the line integral of a region with holes with Green's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595631/taking-the-line-integral-of-a-region-with-holes-with-greens-theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Given an $r\in\>]0,1[\>$ you can consider the annulus $A$ between $C_r$ and $C_1$. You then can apply Green's theorem to this annulus, using $\partial A=C_1-C_r$, where the minus sign indicates that $C_r$ should be taken clockwise. You then have
$$\int_{C_1}F\cdot dr-\int_{C_r}F\cdot dr=\int_{\partial A}F\cdot dr=\int_A(Q_x-P_y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)$$
and can solve for the $C_r$-integral.