# Constant Coefficient Operators: Fundamental solution of Cauchy-Riemann Operator - Folland, Introduction to PDE

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, fundamental-solution

working on the exercises of section F. Constant-Coefficient Operators: Fundamental Solutions but I'm stuck in the following problem:

[image: Exercise]

I'm not sure how to use Green's theorem to conclude the second equality since the classical version works in a domain bounded by picewise smooth curve, but the integration domain is basically the complement of the closed ball $B(0,\varepsilon)$.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: $\phi$ has compact support so you can think think of the domain as an annulus $A_{\epsilon,R}(0)$ centered at the origin with inner and outer radii $\epsilon,R$ respectively, for some very large $R>0$ chosen such that the support of $\phi$ is contained in the open ball $B_R(0)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks I missed this detail

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, this is a sketch of my attempt, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Using the hint, we know that
$$
 \langle LK,\phi\rangle = - \langle K,L\phi\rangle = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\iint_{x^2+y^2>\varepsilon} \frac{\partial_x \phi + i \partial_y \phi}{x+iy}\, dx\,dy \quad \forall \phi\in C^\infty_c
$$
Since $\phi$ has compact support
$$
\iint_{x^2+y^2>\varepsilon} \frac{\partial_x \phi + i \partial_y \phi}{x+iy}\, dx\,dy = \iint_{A_\varepsilon} \frac{\partial_x \phi + i \partial_y \phi}{x+iy}\, dx\,dy
$$
where $A_\varepsilon = B(0,R)\setminus B(0,\varepsilon)$. Using Green's theorem for two regions (see: [Taking the line integral of a region with holes with Green's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595631/taking-the-line-integral-of-a-region-with-holes-with-greens-theorem)) and since $\text{supp}(\phi)\subseteq B(0,R)$

\begin{align}
\iint_{A_\varepsilon} \frac{\partial_x \phi + i \partial_y \phi}{x+iy}\, dx\,dy & = \int_{\partial B(0,R)} \phi(x,y)\,\frac{dx+ idy}{x+iy} + \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \phi(x,y)\,\frac{dx+ idy}{x+iy} \\
& = \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \phi(x,y)\,\frac{dx+ idy}{x+iy}
\end{align}
By the integration over polar coordinates
$$
 \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \phi(x,y)\,\frac{dx+ idy}{x+iy}
= \int_0^{2\pi} \phi(\varepsilon \cos(\theta), \varepsilon \sin\theta)\, d\theta
$$
Finally, let $\varepsilon \to 0$  and by dominated convergence
$$
\langle LK,\phi\rangle = \phi(0,0)
$$
with this, $K$ is a fundamental solution of $L$.